# How to calculate the following limit

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+2x)^{1/x}-(1+x)^{2/x}}{x} $$ I tried calculating it with the e limit but I end up with and undefined limit.I found its $$ -e^2 $$ by putting in numeric values like 1/2 and 1/3 and I saw it gets closer and closer to that but how could I solve it in an algebraic way?Someone suggested I sould simply use the $$ f^g=e^{g\ln f} $$ and then give common factor $$ e^{(1/x)\ln(1+2x)} $$ any ideas?

Comment: I tried with L'Hopital but it got me nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try with standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x} - 1}{x} = 1\tag{1}$$ We can proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 + 2x)^{1/x} - (1 + x)^{2/x}}{x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{\log(1 + 2x)}{x}\right) - \exp\left(\dfrac{2\log(1 + x)}{x}\right)}{x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\exp\left(\dfrac{2\log(1 + x)}{x}\right)\cdot\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{\log(1 + 2x)}{x}-\dfrac{2\log(1 + x)}{x}\right) - 1}{x}\notag\\
&= e^{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{\log(1 + 2x)}{x}-\dfrac{2\log(1 + x)}{x}\right) - 1}{\dfrac{\log(1 + 2x)}{x}-\dfrac{2\log(1 + x)}{x}}\cdot\frac{\log(1 + 2x) - 2\log(1 + x)}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= e^{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + 2x) - 2\log(1 + x)}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= e^{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1 + 2x}{1 + 2x + x^{2}}\right)}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= e^{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log\left(1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{1 + 2x + x^{2}}\right)}{- \dfrac{x^{2}}{1 + 2x + x^{2}}}\cdot\frac{-1}{1 + 2x + x^{2}}\notag\\
&= e^{2}\cdot 1\cdot (-1)\notag\\
&= -e^{2}\notag
\end{align}

Comment: Someone suggested I sould simply use the $$ f^g=e^{glnf} $$ and then give common factor $$ e^\frac{1}{x}ln(1+2x) $$ any ideas?

Comment: @Lola: I have also used the same formula $f^{g} =\exp(g\log f) $. That is way you deal with such expressions.

Comment: I understood it now, I didn't really know what exp meant I thought its a simple exponent ,thank you.

Answer (score 8):

*Using Taylor expansions, namely that of $x\mapsto e^x$ and $x\mapsto\ln(1+x)$ around $0$.*

Rewrite
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(1+2x)^{1/x}-(1+x)^{2/x}}{x}
&= \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+2x)}-e^{\frac{2}{x}\ln(1+x)}}{x}\\
&= \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}(2x-2x^2+o(x^2))}-e^{\frac{2}{x}(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)}}{x}\\
&= \frac{e^{2-2x+o(x)}-e^{2-x+o(x)}}{x}
= e^2\frac{e^{-2x+o(x)}-e^{-x+o(x)}}{x}\\
&= e^2\frac{1-2x+o(x)-(1-x+o(x))}{x}\\
&= e^2\frac{-x+o(x)}{x}= e^2(-1+o(1))\\
&\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} -e^2.
\end{align}$$

We used the two standard Taylor expansions, when $u\to 0$:

- $e^u = 1+u+o(u)$;
- $\ln(1+u) = u - \frac{u^2}{2} +o(u^2)$.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Taylor expansions and I saw that most problems in this book use it.I'll try to figure it out, thank you.

Comment: @Lola It's worth spending some time learning and practicing their use. Even besides the goal of computing limits, they provide a lot of insight about convergence rates, and behaviors of functions around $0$ and $\infty$. ("How does $f(x)$ behave when $x\to\infty$? Is it roughly quadratic, linear?")

Comment: Since this isn't thought in my school and only at college in our country,could you please recommend ,if you know,where I could study it from?

Comment: I do not know of any textbook focusing on this (I myself learnt it from lectures). Maybe looking for lecture notes online would help?

Comment: @Lola I myself learned from Math StackExchange. Stick around, and maybe you will have the same experience!

Comment: I edited the question if you have some ideas on how I could possibly solve it like that..

Comment: @Lola Not sure what you mean by "the common factor," but note that the very first step in my answer is to rewrite $f(x)^{g(x)}$ as $e^{g(x) \ln f(x)}$.

Comment: $$ \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+2x)}(1-e^{??})}{x}\\$$ or something like this so that I can use the limit: $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(e^x-1)}{x}=1 $$

Comment: @Lola Nothing that straigthforward, at least that I can see. You can always factor it, but it won't be as direct and pretty as you hope.

Comment: I tried understanding Taylor Series but I'm having trouble finding what $o(u)$ means and how to calculate it,could you please help?

Comment: @Lola https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
f_{a,b}(x)=(1+ax)^{b/x}=\exp\left(\frac{b\log(1+ax)}{x}\right),
$$
with $a$ and $b$ nonzero constants. Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+ax)}{x}=a
$$
we can extend $f_{a,b}$ to have the value $e^{ab}$ at $0$. We can also compute the derivative of $f_{a,b}$ as
$$
f_{a,b}'(x)=bf_{a,b}(x)\frac{\dfrac{ax}{1+ax}-\log(1+ax)}{x^2}
$$
for $x\ne0$, and it's routine to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f_{a,b}'(x)=-e^{ab}\frac{a^2b}{2}
$$
so $f_{a,b}$ is also differentiable at $0$.

Thus your limit is
$$
f_{2,1}'(0)-f_{1,2}'(0)=
-e^{2\cdot 1}\frac{2^2\cdot1}{2}+e^{1\cdot 2}\frac{1^2\cdot2}{2}=
-e^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+x)^{2/x}\cdot\frac{\left(\dfrac{1+2x}{1+2x+x^2}\right)^{1/x}-1}x$$

$$=\underbrace{\left[(1+x)^{1/x}\right]^2}\cdot\dfrac{\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}\right)^{1/x}-1}x$$

Now $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}=e$

By Binomial Series [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), $$\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}\right)^{1/x}=1-\dfrac x{(x+1)^2}+O(x^2)$$